# MigLayout grow only last row

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, miglayout

I am wanting to grow only the last component in a panel to fill the remaining vertical space.

I currently have:

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("inset 0, filly", "[grow, fill, right][grow, fill, left]"));
```

Which adds padding after each component in order to fill the remaining vertical space. Is there a way to tell MigLayout not to add the padding and grow the last row?

The last row is docked incase that changes anything:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(getTable()), "newline, dock south");
```

Oh, one more thing I forgot to mention (and this is probably important) The amount of rows isn't know at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the dock indeed makes a difference, replacing it with pushy growing cell constraint (and no filly in the layout constraint) works fine. Might be an option if you can live without the dock:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(8, 5)), "span, pushy, growy");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by adding the component constraint of: `height :100%:` and removing the `filly` layout constraint.

My understanding is that this tells the component that it has no minimum size and the preferred size is 100% of it's container. This means that it will take up as much room as possible.

So when you do use the size constraint `:pref:` I believe it's saying "Up to the specified size`

And when you do `min::` I think that resolves to "at least the specified size"?